# What is Virtual Array Antenna?

Tags: communication, power-engineering, mobile, telecommunications

What is virtual array antenna (VAA)?
I have searched it everywhere but i was unable to find direct answer to this question. 
I know this concept was built from phased array antenna. Please explain this concept because i cannot find direct answer to this question.
Thank you.

Comment: I think this may refer to an antenna array where the beam forming is done after the receiver instead of before. This is often done with radio telescopes that are spread out around the world to get better resolution.

Comment: Thank you Alex for the reply. I agree with your answer but it is not what i am looking for. Can you please shed some more light on this topic. I need kick-start on this topic. I have lot of articles with me but still i am unable to visualize VAA.

Comment: Never mind, I was thinking of aperture synthesis interferometry.

Comment: This article talks about virtual array antennas in the context of MIMO SAR: http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijap/2012/587276/ .  See figures 10 and 12.

Comment: Well, virtual array is an mathematical approach to get a better estimation of direction of arrival. It provides better resolution.
We can use MUSIC algorithm and ROOT-MUSIC algorithm to find DOA using array interpolation technique. Alex thanks for the reply but virtual array in MiMO is advance stage. I just started virtual array from SiSO system.